# Firebase hosting not showing up

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

I was hosting a **Flutter Web** project using **Firebase Hosting**.

I did `firebase init` then `firebase deploy` but my hosted website looks like this:

[image]

I think you also this kind of error while hosting.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Answering my own question as I didn't find an answer that helped me out. So I found a way out.

**EDIT(08/2023)**

After doing `firebase init` and selecting the initial options provided by firebase, firebase creates a **firebase.json** file which looks like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

If you do `firebase deploy` here, you'll be seeing the same website as shown in the question.

**Here's what you can do to avoid it.**

- **STEP1**: `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get`
- **STEP2**: Build your application with [either HTML or Canvaskit web renderer](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/renderers)

`flutter build web --web-renderer html --release` (for faster download speed) **OR**

`flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release` (for smooth performance) **OR**

`flutter build web --release` would also work.

- **STEP3**: `firebase init` (Answer the firebase questions carefully)

```
? What do you want to use as your public directory? build/web
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all URLs to /index.html)? yes
? Set up automatic builds and deploy with GitHub? no
? File build/web/index.html already exists. Overwirte? no
```

Now before doing `firebase deploy`, make sure you change the "public" directory to **"build/web"** as shown below, as that is the web flutter has built.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

- **STEP4**: `firebase deploy`

**THINGS TO REMEMBER**

1. Use `build/web` directory instead of `public` as public directory during Firebase initialization
2. DO NOT override `build/web/index.html` as Firebase overrides their own screen (THE SCREEN SHOWN IN THE PROBLEM)

This is all you need to know. Peace✌